# I'm trying to run the SASS compiler in Linux console

Tags: ruby, sass, debian, compass

I have been installed sass on my Debian wheezy laptop, but when I want to run the sass compiler the console display the following error:

```
$ sass --watch develop.scss:style.css
>>> Sass is watching for changes. Press Ctrl-C to stop.
NoMethodError: undefined method `join' for nil:NilClass
  Use --trace for backtrace.
```

- `sass -v` givs "Sass 3.4.6 (Selective Steve)".
- I'm trying to hack the `Gemfile` but not found this file.
- The gems for the compass, listen and ruby and ruby1.9.1-dev have been installed too.

Comment: Did you try using `--trace` for backtrace?

Comment: Yes, but thanks for you help, The problem was related with the logic to use sass, now sass run successfully!